# Background color on full-width child div

Tags: css, margins, margin

I´m trying to set a background color on a div that is stretched (using negative margins) to the full width of its outermost parent div.

Here´s a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/U5dnd/

The white div `.featured-wrapper` covers the full width of the black div `.site`, but its background color doesn´t. I suppose the margins are transparent.

Is there a way to make the whole `.featured-wrapper` div white, including its (negative) margins? (Or is there another way to accomplish this?)

Thanks!

Comment: i am not getting you properly but is http://jsfiddle.net/swamimayank/5JH6w/ you want ?

Comment: Visually speaking, I want the white child div in the example to cover the whole black background, from the left to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.featured-wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    height:50px;
    margin: 20px 0px 0 0px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great in the JSfiddle, though it causes a few other headaches in my templates ;) It seems absolute positioning is the way to go, so I´ll go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/U5dnd/3/)

**CSS:**

```
.site {
    background-color:black;       
    padding: 0 40px;
    height:300px;
    width:320px;
}
.site-content {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:red; 
    height:100%;
}
.featured-wrapper {
    background-color: white;
    height:50px;
    margin: 20px 0 0 -40px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 399px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="page" class="site">

    <div id="main" class="wrapper">

        <div id="primary" class="site-content">
            <div class="featured-wrapper">
                <p>This is the featured wrapper</p>
            </div>
    </div>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Let me know if any change is needed.